# Code is not running, servo does not even spin

Tags: c++, servo

I am trying to run a program which works as follows:

An LDR is integrated in a box. A block is placed on top. This box can be rotated by a servo. The program is supposed to make the box turn until the block slides and lifts off from the LDR.

At that point the servo angle is stored and used to calculate the friction coefficient.

Finally, the answer to this calculation is printed on an LCD and the program repeats by first returning the box to the original state. The entire programs runs on an Arduino and an Arduino Lotus. Why doesn't the servo rotate?

```cpp
//servo 
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo; 
int previous_angle = 0; 
int angle = 0; 
    
//lightsensor 
int lightsensor = 0;     
int LIGHT = 800;     
int DARK = 940; 
              
//LED screen     
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>     
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h> 
    
#define OLED_RESET 4     
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET); 
              
void setup() {    
  Serial.begin(9600);     
  myservo.attach(6); 
            
  pinMode(lightsensor, INPUT);               

  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C); 
    
  delay(100);                 
} 
              
void loop() { 
  int i = previous_angle;     
  int lightStatus = analogRead(lightsensor); 
    
  if (lightStatus >= DARK) {      
    delay(300); 

    while (int i = previous_angle) {
      i<=90;
      i = i+1;
      myservo.write(i);     
      delay(45); 
    };      
  } else if (lightStatus < DARK) {    
    for (int i = previous_angle; i>0;) {     
      delay(300);     
      int angle = tan(i);         
      display.clearDisplay();     
      display.setTextSize(1.5);     
      display.setTextColor(WHITE);     
      display.setCursor(0,0);     
      display.println(angle);     
      display.display();     
      delay(300);  
              
      myservo.write(0);     
      delay(45);     
    };     
  }     
}
```

Comment: In the future, please format your source code using the {} on this site.  As it was it was very difficult to follow your code.  Also, please include a schematic of how your motor is connected.

Comment: Question: Have you been able to make your motor run with just a simple program?  It's often helpful to start out simple and add things one step at a time.

Answer (score 2):

For starters: this bit is a strange mixture of `for` and `while` syntax:

```cpp
while (int i = previous_angle) {
  i <= 90; 
  i = i + 1; 
  myservo.write(i);
  delay(45); 
};
```

It will compile, but probably not do what you want it to do. It should probably be:

```cpp
for (int i=previous_angle; i<=90; i=i+1) {
  myservo.write(i);
  delay(45); 
}
```

Also, `previous_angle` is never changed in your code after initialisation; it is always 0.

That also means that the `for` loop below will not do what you want (and that loop also doesn't increment `i` anywhere):

```cpp
for (int i = previous_angle; i>0;)
```

There may be more; make the suggested changes first and see what happens.

Comment: If I change it I get an error when verifying the code 'expected ')' before ';' token'

Comment: I blame coffee underflow 8-). Answer edited.

Comment: Changing to a "for" does resolve the error, I will check whether the code also properly as needed thankyou